# SQL - On insert, reference ColumnA value in ColumnB

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am wondering if it is possible in SQL (in particular SQL server) when inserting a record with multiple columns to reference ColumnA's value in ColumnB's relative to that record.

In terms of pseudocode, here is a simplistic example of what I am envisioning:

```
INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES 
(Value1, this.ColumnA), -- (e.g. 1, 1)
(Value2, this.ColumnA), -- (e.g. 5, 5)
(Value3, this.ColumnA), -- (e.g. 10, 10)
...
```

I understand there are many alternatives ways to add one value to different columns, however I am looking to see is if this is a possible method.

Comment: In TSQL itself? No.  In any other method I know of to access SQL Server (and I don't know ALL the different languages and methods that are in use accessing SQL Server)... no.

Comment: @LaughingVergil TSQL falls within the scope of what technology I'm using (added the tsql tag to reflect this). Thanks for your reply it's good to get a definitive answer.

Comment: Why not just repeat the value for ColumnA?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve here? Have you looked at computed columns?

Comment: @Isaac ColumnA are all hardcoded values with different variables, in terms of scalability and time consumption I'm trying to prevent having to hardcode the same value just to do some additional logic.

Comment: @JacobH problem is ColumnA are all hardcoded values, ColumnB uses ColumnA's value to do additional logic to determine ColumnB's value

Comment: Yes, that sounds exactly like what a computed column would be used for.

Comment: @JacobH computed columns are a new concept to myself, this is an even better approach than I was thinking of logically and code writing wise.

Comment: Just note, there are some limitations and performance impacts, but that is also the case for triggers and doing an insert-then-update. One method could be better than the other, depending on the circumstance. Generally, I think a computed column is going to be superior to a trigger updating the same table. [This thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/136733/when-are-computed-columns-computed) on DBA.stackexchange is a solid resource.

Comment: @JacobH excellent resource, especially on considering PERSISTED and storage on use cases.

Answer (score 1):

You may have just provided an over simplistic example, but why not just do something like this?:

```sql
INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES 
(Value1, Value1), -- (e.g. 1, 1)
(Value2, Value2), -- (e.g. 5, 5)
(Value3, Value3), -- (e.g. 10, 10)
...
```

On top of that, again, your example may just be over simplified, but if they're the same value then why do you need 2 separate columns when you could just have one like so:

```sql
INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnA) VALUES ('Value1'), ('Value2'), ('Value3')
```

Comment: You are right, over simplified. Should of mentioned that these values are all hardcoded values and ColumnB has additional logic in it to determine ColumnB's value

Answer (score 1):

There are not many ways to emulate this, and none are straightforward.

An `INSERT` trigger on the target table. An INSTEAD OF trigger could change the insert, adding `inserted.ColumnA` as the value for `inserted.ColumnB` if `inserted.ColumnB` was `NULL`.

An `UPDATE` query could be run after the VALUES are added to `ColumnA`, copying `ColumnA` values to `ColumnB` if `ColumnB IS NULL` (assuming `NULL` is allowed in the column), or is some false value (e.g. If `ColumnB` was an `int`, and the values were always positive, add a -1 value as the default value in your `VALUES` statement for `ColumnB`, then `UPDATE... WHERE ColumnB < 0`

Those are the most straightforward ways that I can think of

Answer (score 0):

No, especially because SQL isn't an OOP language, so you can't access an Object that doesn't exist using the reserved word "this".